# Isomorphism on a torsion group - automorphism or endomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, torsion-groups

Let $f:G\to G$ be a surjection from a torsion group $G$ onto itself.

Let the kernel have infinite cardinality: $\lvert\ker(f)\rvert=\aleph_0$

> What category of function on groups is this?

To my mind this cannot be a group automorphism because at the very least an automorphism must map the identity onto itself in order to satisfy $f(a\cdot b)=f(a)\circ f(b)$.

Clearly $f$ does not yield distinct inverses.

Is $f$ therefore an endomorphism instead?

In part, I'm asking whether an endomorphism on a torsion group can have a kernel with infinite cardinality - what with the elements themselves having finite order and all.

I'm asking with half an eye on groups of intermediate growth such as the [Grigorchuk group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group), and any torsion group structure on which variants of the Collatz function might be an endomorphism.

Comment: Well, the trivial homomorphism is an endomorphism with infinite cardinality if the group is infinite...

Comment: Endomorphism is just a homomorphism from an object to itself. Yes, every morphism $G\to G$ is an endomorphism **by definition**. Did you perhaps mean epimorphism? Also if the kernel is nontrivial then obviously a homomorphism is not injective. And so it is not an automorphism.

Comment: Anyway if you actualy meant "epimorphism" then there still can be an epimorphism $G\to G$ with infinite kernel. Take $G=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}_2$ and map $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots)$ to $(x_1, x_3, x_5, x_7,\ldots)$.

Comment: So you are looking for non-Hopfian torsion groups. It's easy to construct examples  such as the direct product of  infinitely many copies of the same finite group. The question would be more interesting if you assumed that $G$ is finitely generated. I don't know immediately whether there are any such examples.

Comment: Grigorchuck group would not work since every quotient is finite. I don't know of any finitely generated non hopfian torsion groups(they could exist, but it might be an open problem if they do too)

Comment: @freakish yes epimorphism looks right. Sorry to be a pain but I'm relatively inexperienced in communicating in such matters - is your $\Bbb Z_2$ the 2-adic $\Bbb Z_2$?  Derek's comment would imply you mean $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, is that right?

Comment: @PaulPlummer please excuse my ignorance but I presume from your comment there's some obvious relation between the epimorphism and some quotient.  It would be most helpful if you could mention that relation for me.

Comment: @RobertFrost Yes, formally $\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is the group of integers modulo $2$. The finite group of $2$ elements.

Comment: The image of a homomorphism is isomorphic to the group quotient out by the kernel. So having a surjective group homomorphism to $G \to G$ with nontrivial kernel means you have a proper quotient $G/\ker \cong G$

Comment: @DonAntonio the question is asking for surjective homomorphism

Comment: @DonAntonio I assumed there was some misunderstanding on my part, I was just trying to work out what it was.  I understood the trivial homomorphism to be the identity homomorphism $\forall x\in G:f:x\mapsto x$ but I now think you meant $\forall x\in G:x\mapsto 1_G$. Is that correct? Is the trivial homomorphism the standard name for that?  Then I thought, maybe the identity is some set with infinite cardinality then you might say the map $1_G\mapsto 1_G$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$

Comment: @PaulPlummer Indeed, I missed that condition. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an accepted name to those types of functions except for saying what they are: surjective homomorphism with some specified size of kernel. You can say surjective endomorphism, or epic endomorphsims(which sounds sort of cool). The endomorphism means it is a morphism between the same object. In the category of groups surjective morphisms and epimorphism/epic morphism are the same(in general they are nor the same thing).

You mention your motiviation is studying torsion groups of intermediate growth(so finitely generated) with a function like the above. As far as I can tell, it is not known if such torsion f.g. groups exist even without the condition of intermediate growth. The Grigorchuck group does not have any homomorphism like that since it is *just infinite* which is an infinite group where all proper quotients are finite.

Without finitely generated condition there are groups like that, for example  $ \bigoplus_{i \in  \mathbb N} \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks. The critical thing I drew from the comments which isn't in this answer was that this is a non-isomorphic epimorphism and therefore the group would be non Hopfian. I suspect the object I'm trying to construct is more likely akin to your infinitely generated example though.

Comment: Sure, that is the definition of non-hopfian group. I didn't bring it up since you didn't ask about it in the question(just what to call such f), although it is good to mention. There are plenty of finitely generated non-hopfian groups, just don't know of any torsion examples(and I think it is probably an open question if such exist).

Comment: A direct product was mentioned but I guess what you show here is an infinite sum. Then I guess either would suffice?

Comment: @RobertFrost You could do something similar with direct products, but the easy maps give uncountable kernel(I actually wouldn't be surprised if any such mapping must have uncountable kernel or finite kernel when dealing with infinite products).

Comment: @RobertFrost Another word about infinite product case is that there is a natural topology(the product topology) to put on such groups and frequently homomorphisms between such groups are forced to be continuous in this topology. This is called automatic continuity. As an example, it can be used to prove infinite product of integers is not free abelian (even though in the finite case they are). This continuity frequently means kernels will be very large or small.

Comment: thanks, that is potentially useful. I'm trying to shoehorn the Collatz graph into a group structure in which numbers closer to 1 are of lower exponent. It's isomorphic to a Prufer p group except with p equal to omega. In other words isomorphic to the set of ordinals writable in Cantor normal form of unlimited length. Ultimately the torsion property may be incorrect.

Comment: Sorry upon reflection I should have written the set of ordinals writable in Cantor normal form, with only integer exponents.